# Algebra solve for x: $0.05 = \frac{52.11x}{5000+x}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am trying to solve for $x$ in the following equation:

$$0.05 = \frac{52.11x}{5000+x}$$

Wolfram Alpha's solve for $x$ calculator did not provide a solution, which is not a good sign. I do not have a strong enough grasp of algebra to understand why.

Your insight is appreciated!

I'm not exactly sure where to start. The $5000+x$ in the denominator is throwing me off. I tried splitting the fraction into $$\frac{52.11x}{1} \cdot \frac{1}{5000+x}$$ and then dividing $0.05$ by $52.11x$. But I'm not sure where to go from there.

Comment: This equation does have a solution.   Have you tried solving it algebraically?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure where to start. The $5000 + x$ in the numerator is throwing me off. I tried splitting the fraction into $\frac{52.11x}{1}*\frac{1/5000+x}$ and then dividing $0.05$ by $52.11x$. But I'm not sure where to go from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments, there is a solution.  You may have entered the expression into Wolfram Alpha incorrectly.

If we multiply both sides of the equation 
$$0.05 = \frac{52.11x}{5000 + x}$$
by $5000 + x$, we obtain
$$0.05(5000 + x) = 52.11x$$
Applying the distributive law $a(b + c)$ on the left-hand side yields
$$250 + 0.05x = 52.11x$$
Subtracting $0.05x$ from both sides of the equation yields
$$250 = 52.06x$$
Since equality is symmetric,
$$52.06x = 250$$
Dividing both sides of the equation by $52.06$ yields 
$$x = \frac{250}{52.06} \approx 4.80$$

**Check:**  If we substitute $4.80$ for $x$ in the expression
$$\frac{52.11x}{5000 + x}$$
we obtain
$$\frac{52.11 \cdot 4.80}{5000 + 4.80} = \frac{250.128}{5004.80} \approx 0.05$$

**Note:** In the comments, you incorrectly referred to $5000 + x$ as the numerator.  It is actually the denominator of the expression
$$\frac{52.11x}{5000 + x}$$
The numerator of that expression is $52.11x$.

Comment: Thank you! I was able to follow these steps. I really need to start practicing more algebra problems.  Also, I did mean to say denominator instead of numerator. I think it's best for me to call it quits at work as the law of diminishing return is strong. Thanks again for the response.